# React-redux connect method unable to locate store in props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a application structure that mostly mimics the redux [real-world](https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) example but can't get past getting this error:

`Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Home)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Home)".`

Here follows my application structure:

## render

```
import { render, createFactory } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import router from './router/router'
import store from './flux/store'

window.onload = () => {
    render(createFactory(Provider)({store: store},
        () => router
    ), document.body)
};
```

## Router

```
import { _ } from 'factories'
import { Router, IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router'
import history from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

import Home from '../components/home/home'

let route = _(Route),
    index = _(IndexRoute);

let router = _(Router)({history: history()},
    route({path: 'home', component: Home})
);

export default router;
```

## Home Component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { div } from 'factories'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as users from '../../flux/actions/users'

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {}
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props.users.user)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {

    }

    render() {

        return (
            div({}, "Home")
        )
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => {
        return {
            users: state.users
        }
    },
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(users, dispatch)
)(Home)
```

This results in getting the above mentioned error. as you can see I am passing the store in the same manner as shown in the redux example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was found in [redux troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting). I needed to have my react-router return a function that created the actual router:

```
import { _ } from 'factories'
import { Router, IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router'
import history from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

import Home from '../components/home/home'

let route = _(Route),
    index = _(IndexRoute);

const router = () =>
    _(Router)({history: history()},
        route({path: 'home', component: Home})
    );
export default router;
```

Comment: Same side effect. I had the createStore() return an object (was wrapped in curly braces). Once I changed them to braces (i.e return a function), the error went away .... thanks for the hint.